# Getting an error ; 'int' object not callable

Tags: python

this the block of code i wrote

```
def shapeArea(n):
b=[]
t=0
i=1
while(n!=0):
    b.append(4(n-(n-i)))
k=int(len(b))
for l in range(k):
    t+=b[i]
return t
```

The error i am getting on passing a value to the function:

```
TypeError:'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: in while loop add a line: i=i+1

Comment: Hint: `b.append(4(…))`

Comment: @shoaibqureshi what are you trying to calculate using this function, can you add that part in the question

Comment: i want to add the elements in the list b, and return it as an answer @zenwraight

Comment: Can you indent your method properly according to python standards

Comment: `4(n-(n-i))` looks like you're trying to call a function named `4`.

Comment: watch your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is that you are trying to do, but your issue will be resolved by making the below modification.

Existing code:

```
b.append(4(n-(n-i)))
```

Change it to:

```
b.append(4*(n-(n-i)))
```

Please note, with the changes I am seeing your code is going into infinite loop which is due to logic issue.

Comment: it worked, and i removed the while loop did it with for loop,

Comment: Glad it help. If you have got the answer, please mark the comment as answered/+1. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are new to stackoverflow. Please refer [Stackoverflow Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to see how to mark a comment as answered.